# Stop new command window opening each time command is executed

Tags: c#

I have written a C# tool that will launch an application by running a command in the command prompt for me several times, one after the other. The piece of code doing this for me is as follows:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

So I have this in a loop and all is good. However each time it executes a new command window is opened, which isnt ideal. Is there a way I can close the command window after the command has executed, or better still, not have the command window open at all? Any help is really appreciated!!

Comment: Why do you need to launch an application? What do the commands look like?

Comment: Have you looked at the various ways you can start a process through the Process class? In particular, have you looked at the overloads with ProcessStartInformation ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you have to use the `ProcessStartInfo` class for doing this:

```
Process.Start(
    new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", strCmdText) 
        { 
            CreateNoWindow = true 
        });
```

Comment: I believe you also need to set `UseShellExecute = false;`.

Comment: Brilliant, just for completion you need to add using System.Diagnostics;

Answer (score 1):

Use `ProcessStartInfo` to start the process (`Start` has an overload that takes a `ProcessStartInfo`).

Set the following properties:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", strCmdText);
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;

Process.Start(psi);
```

Answer (score 1):

ProcessStartInfo allows you to specify no window.

```
using (var p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "CMD.exe",
        Arguments = strCmdText,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    };

    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    p.Close();
}
```